# retrieving values from resolved Promise object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to get the values out of an array of promises.

```
  async function retrieveIssues() {
  
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(argv.i);
  let issues = JSON.parse(rawdata);

  const issuesArray = issues.Issues;

  const promises = issuesArray.map(issue => getIssueInfo(issue));

  await Promise.all(promises);


  // promises is now array of current issue information
  console.log(promises)
  console.log(promises[0])


}
```

So what I have is an array of Promise objects that look like this:

```
    Promise {
  { title: 'Work',
  body: 'We\'ve had...\n',
  labels: [ [Object] ] } }
```

So how would I get access to the title, for example?

Comment: `Promise.all` returns an array mapped to the resolved values of the provided Promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still using the `promises` variable to try to access the values, when you want to use the result of your awaited `Promise.all` call instead. EG:

```
const results = await Promise.all(promises);


// promises is now array of current issue information
console.log(results);
console.log(results[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It helps to understand how promises behave to know what to do with [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Without `async/await`, your code would look like this:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
  // results is now an array of current issue information
  console.log(results)
  console.log(results[0])
  console.log(results[0].title)
})
```

When you use `await`, the value that would normally be retrieved inside the `then` gets returned, so you need to store it in a variable and use that. Thus you get:

```
let results = await Promises.all(promises)
// results is now an array of current issue information
console.log(results)
console.log(results[0])
console.log(results[0].title)
```

Comment: Even without `async`/`await` you could make the mistake of doing `Promise.all(promises).then(() => { console.log(promises); })` :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the title as-

```
let promise = await Promise.all(promises);    
console.log(promise[0].title);
```